# How do you update JRuby's gem command?

Tags: rubygems, jruby

**How do we update the version of gem that JRuby uses?**

JRuby uses gem (1.5.1) and we would like to upgrade it to 1.8.7. We want to have the gems installed in Ruby/gems

We run:

```
bin/jruby gem install rubygems-update
Fetching: rubygems-update-1.8.5.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rubygems-update-1.8.5
1 gem installed

bin/jruby gem install --system
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
invalid option: --system
```

(update does not work either)

```
bin/jruby gem update --system
Updating RubyGems
Updating RubyGems to 1.8.5
Installing RubyGems 1.8.5
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EBADF)
Bad file descriptor - Bad file descriptor
```

How can the install/update of gem (1.8.5) be done?

**Configuration:**

- using Maven to install JRuby.
- JRuby is installed at:
   ~/.m2/repository/org/jruby/jruby-complete/1.6.3/jruby-complete-1.6.3.jar
- jruby-complete-1.6.3.jar is NOT exploded.
- jruby-complete-1.6.3.jar has built the "gem" (1.5.1) command into it.
- command `bin/jruby` that looks like this:

(bin/jruby)

```
export jruby_build=1.6.3
export GEM_HOME= ~/tools/ruby/gems
java -jar ~/.m2/repository/org/jruby/jruby-complete/${jruby_build}/jruby-complete-${jruby_build}.jar -S $*
```

- Environment variables:

(env)

```
GEM_HOME=~/tools/ruby/gems
GEM_PATH=~/tools/ruby/gems
```

Answer (score 4):

If you can get update_rubygems to work, that's fine, but be aware that this may cause some JRuby-specific extensions to no longer work (e.g., maven integration). We ship RubyGems with JRuby releases so that we can ensure our extensions are compatible with the version we ship.

Comment: I haven't had success yet. (I had to put it aside and just workaround the issue - whatever it maybe).

Comment: How do you get around the issue of gems not installing? The version of rubygems shipped with jruby (even 1.6.4) doesn't allow the installing of gems. It dies a horrible death.

Answer (score 0):

Having installed `rubygems-update`, you then need to execute the command:

```
jruby -S update_rubygems
```

From then on, you should be able to use the normal command, i.e.

```
jruby -S gem update --system
```

Comment: no. Please look at the bin/jruby code I supplied. I do provide the '-S' option.

Comment: Hmmm I'm looking and I'm not seeing it.  But anyway, the `-S` is not the problem.  The problem is you used the `install` command instead of the `update` command, which is what I was trying to point out.

Comment: when i was creating the question, I forgot to include that I did try to do the gem update with no success either.

Comment: (modified the original question)

Comment: (modified the answer to suit)

Comment: This does not work, same error results as the original question's post.

Comment: @BeepDog can you be more specific (there are two errors in the original post)?  Better yet: raise a new question.

Comment: Make sure you look at Nick Sieger's response - the answer seems to be that you're limited to the gem that ships with jruby.

Comment: How does one install `rubygems-update`? `gem install rubygems-update-2.0.15` doesn't make `jruby -S update_rubygems` work: `jruby: No such file or directory -- update_rubygems (LoadError)`